# How to configure AutoMySQLBackup?

Tags: mysql, backup, automation

How I can configure AutoMySQLBackup to backup some selected tables ones per week while the other tables will be backed up every day?

Thanks.

P.S. My google search ninja skills is not working. :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the AutoMySQLBackup documention you can supply an alternate configuration file:

From https://github.com/rcruz/AutoMySQLBackup/blob/master/README

> Thee backup can be run from the command line simply by running the
>   following command.
>
> automysqlbackup /etc/automysqlbackup/myserver.conf
>
> If you don't supply an argument for automysqlbackup, the default
>   configuration in the program automysqlbackup will be used unless a
>   global file
>
> CONFIG_configfile="/etc/automysqlbackup/automysqlbackup.conf"
>
> exists

So that means you can simply use a different config file, and schedule two different runs in crontab.

That... or you can always roll your own, which I find more flexible.

```
#!/bin/bash

OUTPUT="/mnt/backups/"

rm -f "$OUTPUTDIR/*.bz2" > /dev/null 2>&1

databases=`mysql -e "SHOW DATABASES;" | tr -d "| " | grep -v Database`

for db in $databases
do
    if [[ "$db" != "information_schema" ]] && [[ "$db" != "performance_schema" ]] && [[ "$db" != "mysql" ]] && [[ "$db" != _* ]] ; then
        echo "Dumping database: $db"
        mysqldump --quick --set-gtid-purged=OFF --databases $db | bzip2 > $OUTPUT/$db.sql.bz2
    fi
done
```